R Reactable add prefix to column based on condition
I have a dataframe with two columns: Condition & Value.
Based on this dataframe I would like to create a reactable object.
The Value column should have a prefix.
It should be preceded by “Check” if the Condition column is TRUE.
Unfortunately, I could not think of a solution to include a condition in the following code.
library(reactable)

df <- data.frame(
  Condition = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
  Value = c(100, 200, 300, 400)
)

reactable(
  df,
  columns = list(
    Value = colDef(format = colFormat(prefix = "Check"))
  )
)

Here is the desired output:


Why don't you first format the dataframe before making it a reactable object?

@IfeanyiIdiaye Unfortunately, this is not possible in my use case. That's why I prefer a solution within colDef().
